# Webpack build stuck on middle of creation of bundle

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, babel-loader

I use webpack to build and tun my app locally. I use babel, ts loader, sass loader. I have pretty big codebase. Couple days ago I found that webpack cant build my app. It stuck on bundling job on 48% or 52%. I fixed it with --max_old_space_siz but now it does not help. What can i do with that issue?

I run webpack serve in development mode.

```
"ts-loader": "9.3.1",
"webpack": "5.74.0",
"webpack-bundle-analyzer": "4.6.1"
"babel-loader": "7.18.9"
```